# Sequence convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, probability-limit-theorems

If we consider $(Xn)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, a sequence of independent random variables satisfying:
$$ P(X_n = 1) = p_n \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; P(X_n = 0) = 1 − p_n$$
then :

$$X_n \;{\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}} \;0 ⇔\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} p_n < ∞$$

I couldn't show the first implication from convergence a.s to the sum of $p_n$ is finite!

Comment: This should be a straightforward application of [Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)

Comment: Yes, I know but I mean for the implication that shows that if we have $x_n$ converge towards 0 a.s then the sum is finite

Answer (score 0):

In this context with $X_n$ independent, the [partial converse to Borel-Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) reads: $$\sum p_n=\infty \implies P(X_n=1\text{ i.o.})=1.$$ The contrapositive of that statement is that $$P(X_n=1\text{ i.o.})\neq 1 \implies \sum p_n <\infty.$$
(Note that by the [zero-one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) $P(X_n=1\text{ i.o.})\in\{0,1\}$.) The key assumption here is independence: we didn't need it to show $\sum p_n<\infty \implies X_n\to0$ a.s., but it is necessary for the partial converse to Borel-Cantelli.

Another way to see this whole thing is to let $X_n$ be the indicator random variables for the events $E_n$ in the typical phrasing of the Borel-Cantelli lemma and its partial converse. Then of course $p_n=P(E_n)$ and $P(E_n\text{ i.o.})=0$ is the same as $X_n\to0$. So this is really just rephrasing that lemma in terms of Bernoulli random variables instead of events, but those are more or less equivalent ideas.